# Spring MyBatis expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency

Tags: spring, select, annotations, javabeans, mybatis

i have a trouble with my Spring MyBatis Project.
Here the classes of the 4 packages tiers:
controller
mapper
model
service

com.mb.alf.controller

ServizioController.java

```
package com.mb.alf.controller;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import com.mb.alf.model.Servizio;
import com.mb.alf.service.ServizioService;

@Controller
@SessionAttributes("servizio")
public class ServizioController {

    @Autowired
    private ServizioService servizioService;

    @RequestMapping("/returnServizio")
    public ModelAndView returnServizio() {
        Servizio servizio = servizioService.getServizio();
        return new ModelAndView("returnServizio", "servizio", servizio);    }}
```

com.mb.alf.mapper

ServizioMapper.java

```
package com.mb.alf.mapper;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Select;
import com.mb.alf.model.Servizio;

public interface ServizioMapper {

    @Select("select s.ser_puntopresa, s.ser_oldcodser from serviz s where s.ser_ute = '01' and S.SER_PUNTOPRESA = 101")
      public   Servizio  getServizio();
}
```

com.mb.alf.model

Servizio.java

```
package com.mb.alf.model;

public class Servizio {
     Integer serv_puntopresa;
     Integer ser_oldcodser;

    public Integer getSer_oldcodser() {
        return ser_oldcodser;   }

    public void setSer_oldcodser(Integer ser_oldcodser) {
        this.ser_oldcodser = ser_oldcodser; }

    public Integer getServ_puntopresa() {
        return serv_puntopresa;    }

    public void setServ_puntopresa(Integer num) {
        this.serv_puntopresa = num;    }
}
```

com.mb.alf.service

ServizioService.java

```
package com.mb.alf.service;
import com.mb.alf.model.Servizio;

public interface ServizioService {

    Servizio  getServizio();    
    }
```

ServizioServiceImpl.java

```
package com.mb.alf.service;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired; 
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component; 
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import com.mb.alf.mapper.ServizioMapper; 
import com.mb.alf.model.Servizio;

@Component @Service("servizioService") 
public class ServizioServiceImpl implements  ServizioService {

     @Autowired       
     private ServizioMapper   servizioMapper;

     @Transactional     
     public Servizio getServizio() {                
        return servizioMapper.getServizio();    }   }
```

Here my XML files:

web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>myBatisServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/springConfig.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>myBatisServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

springConfig.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
  xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mb.alf" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@MYHOST:orcl"/>
        <property name="username" value="USER"/>
        <property name="password" value="PASSWORD"/>
    </bean>  

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="com.mb.alf.model"/>
  <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath*:com/mb/alf/mapper/*.xml" />
</bean>

<bean id="sqlSession" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
  <constructor-arg index="0" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
  <property name="basePackage" value="com.mb.alf.mappers" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

It gets this Exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servizioController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.mb.alf.service.ServizioService com.mb.alf.controller.ServizioController.servizioService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servizioService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.mb.alf.mapper.ServizioMapper com.mb.alf.service.ServizioServiceImpl.servizioMapper; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.mb.alf.mapper.ServizioMapper] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Please, how and where  can I implement the correct bean?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should seperate the mybatis setup in another xml instead of putting it in current springConfig.xml

For example:

**web.xml** add the following:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:conf/spring.xml;
        classpath:conf/spring-mybatis.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
...
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

In **spring-mybatis.xml***, add your dataSource, transactionManager, sqlSessionFactory, sqlSession and org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer.

One example can be found here https://github.com/liratanak/SpdSample-Spring-MVC-3-MyBatis-3-Tiles-3